# Having trouble converting a simple Objective-C block to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using this module https://github.com/wenzhaot/InstagramPhotoPicker (the header file for the block is here https://github.com/wenzhaot/InstagramPhotoPicker/blob/master/TWPhotoPicker/TWPhotoPickerController.h)

In Objective-C, the syntax is:

```
photoPicker.cropBlock = ^(UIImage *image) {
    //do something
};
```

I tried converting it to swift, but I'm getting an error

```
photoPicker.cropBlock{ (image:UIImage) -> () in
    //Do something
    //error: cannot invoke 'cropBlock' with an argument list of type '((UIImage) -> ())'
}
```

How to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing `=` sign. Also `image` is implicitly unwrapped optional:

```
photoPicker.cropBlock = { (image: UIImage!) -> () in
    //Do something
}
```

or

```
photoPicker.cropBlock = { image in
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Also the `UIImage` is implicitly unwrapped optional. Notice the `!` in your error message. See my revised answer.